# Angular 2; reuse a subcomponent identical form in several parent components keeping state

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I know this title looks familiar; however I've been struggling to find anyone having the same problem I am. Maybe I'm not sure how to phrase the question? Explanation below:

**Use case:**

I have several routes (in the sample below only 2) set up each going to their respective components - I will call these parent components. On the main page, a user can switch between the parent components by clicking on links which navigate the router.  Each of these parent components shares an identical form.  The form contains identical settings for rendering each parent component, and when navigating between routes of parent components the state of the form should persist.  So I've abstracted that form to be its own component.  For this form to render properly it must make a call to our backend and retrieve a list.

**Problem:**

When I open the page (which redirects to component 'A') the form loads perfectly.  It works precisely how I expect it to.  But when I navigate to component 'B' angular appears to be creating a new instance of my SharedFormComponent, and is never calling ngOnInit on it.  This causes a predictable error when the form cannot render as it has no data in it's list to do so.  The same can be said in reverse.  When the page is initialized with the route pointing to component 'B' the form works perfectly.  But as soon as I navigate to route '/a' the form cannot render properly which kills the page.

**Expectation:**

Ideally, this form would be reused entirely.  It would keep the same state, all it's attributes, etc. but would re-render as a sub section of the different parent components when navigating between them. How can I do this?

If this is not possible, I'm willing to compromise (with reservations) and have multiple instances of the form laying around, eating into my memory. How is this achievable?

**Routes**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: '/a'},
    {path: 'a', component: AComponent},
    {path: 'b', component: BComponent}
```

**A.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
    selector: "comp-a",
    template: "
        <shared-form-component> </shared-form-component>
        <hr>
        <p> other stuff A </p>
    "
})
export class AComponent {
    constructor() {}
}
```

**B.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
    selector: "comp-b",
    template: "
        <shared-form-component> </shared-form-component>
        <hr>
        <p> other stuff B </p>
    "
})
export class BComponent {
    constructor() {}
}
```

**SharedForm.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
    selector: "shared-form-component",
    providers: [ MyService ],
    template: "
        <shared-form-component> </shared-form-component>
        <hr>
        <p> other stuff </p>
    "
})
export class SharedFormComponent implements OnInit {
    data: Datum[];
    constructor(private service: MyService) {}
    ngOnInit() {
        this.service.fetchData().subscribe(data => {
            this.data = data;
        });
    }
}
```

**App.component.ts**

```js
@Component({
    selector: "shared-form-component",
    template: "
        <a [routerLink]=["/a"]> a </>
        <a [routerLink]=["/b"]> b </>
        <hr>
        <router-outlet> </router-outlet>
    "
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor() {}
}
```

*edit: fixes component class names.*

Comment: This is weird, it's not supposed to skip the `ngOnOnit` lifecycle... What kind of form are you using ? A reactive form or template-driven ? To me you are doing it correctly, having a shared component and a service managing the data in it. Just one point, why not having the `fetchData()` in the shared component since it's supposed to manage it's own data ?

Comment: The form is a simple template with two `select` elements. The `option`s in the `select` elements are populated by list attributes which are populated by the service call. Regarding your question; the data the service provides may be used by multiple components, it also manages client-side caching for me to avoid repeat calls for the same data and thus should not be part of the shared component.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like a dufus. The issue was completely unrelated to `ngOnInit`; a more careful inspection of the stack trace revealed the exception had to do with event timing of something else entirely... completely my fault. Apologies.

Comment: Ahah I though so